# How to take a value from one jQuery function and assign it to a parameter of another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters, arguments

I have a function with a jQuery slider. It sets up a delay time and shows it in the "#slider" div :

```
$(function () {
    $("#slider").slider({
        range: 'max',
        min: 1,
        max: 5,
        slide: function(event,ui) {
            $("#delayTime").val(ui.value);
                delayTime = ui.value * 1000;            
        }
    });  
});
```

This works OK by itself.

Later in the code I have another function which runs the whole slideshow. 
That function has its own parameter which determines a delay time between each slide:

```
function mySlideshow(){
    var wholeSlideshow =
        $('#thumbHolder').galleryWithSlideshow({
            mainCntrls: true,
            prevNextCntrls: true,

            delayTime: 2000,    


            etc.     

   });
```

This one works perfectly fine by itself too.

Question.

What should I add to the code to pass the value I get in the slider function 
into the slideshow function's delayTime parameter so the slider function would determine the
delayTime in the slideshow function?

I was considering modifying the slider function like this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#slider").slider({
        range: 'max',
        min: 1,
        max: 5,
        slide: function(event,ui) {
            $("#delayTime").val(ui.value);
                delayTime = ui.value * 1000;
                return delayTime;           
        }
    });  
});
```

as well as adding into the slideshow function's delayTime parameter something like this:

```
delay: function (event, ui){
        $("#delayTime").val(delayTime);
},
```

Although I could not make it work.

Any ideas?
I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but what is `galleryWithSlideshow` ? Is it from a plugin or something ?

Answer (score 1):

Declare a variable myDelayTime before, outside your functions. It will be accessible throughout the code.

```
var myDelayTime;

$(function () {
    $("#slider").slider({
        range: 'max',
        min: 1,
        max: 5,
        slide: function(event,ui) {
            $("#delayTime").val(ui.value);
                delayTime = ui.value * 1000;  
                myDelayTime = delayTime;  
        }
    });
});

...

delay: function (event, ui){
        $("#delayTime").val(myDelayTime);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the parameter into jQuery.data:

```
 $(function () {
    $("#slider").slider({
        range: 'max',
        min: 1,
        max: 5,
        slide: function(event,ui) {
            $("#delayTime").val(ui.value);
                delayTime = ui.value * 1000;
                $("#slider").data("delayTime",delayTime);       
        }
    });  
});
```

Then get it in anywhere:

```
delay: function (event, ui){
        $("#delayTime").val($("#slider").data("delayTime"));
},
```